# ios compile ffmpeg without ac3 support

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, compilation

I'm making a video player for iOS Devices. I use a ffmpeg libraries to play the video files. I see the problems that have other video players in the App Store with the AC3 sound support.

I want that my video player don't works with AC3 sound. I'm looking for arguments in the compile script ffmpeg libraries like a `--enable-gpl` and `--enable-nonfree`, but not works.

I read the licenses of ffmpeg libraries several times and I think that I don't understand well.

Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: What problem, you just don't support ac3 its as simple as that, if someone hacks your app after the fact I think it falls under the same legal considerations involving jail breaking.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `--disable-decoder=ac3` to ffmeg configure arguments.